# Variable isn't changing after form submitting

Tags: php, forms

the problem is that my variable `$target_time` doesn't work well.

```
if (isset($_POST['bid'])) {
  $stmt10->execute(array(
  'user_id' => $usid,
  'user' => $login,
  'bid' => $_SESSION['bid']
  ));
}

$target_time = strtotime('+15 minutes', strtotime($stmt14));
$current_time = time();

echo $current_time . ' >= ' . $target_time;

$seconds_left = $target_time - $current_time;
$minutes_left = floor($seconds_left / 60);
$seconds_left -= $minutes_left * 60;
$seconds_left = floor($seconds_left);  

if ($current_time >= $target_time) {
  $stmt9->execute();  
  $r1 = $stmt9->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
  $stmt12->execute();      
  $r2 = $stmt12->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);  
  $stmt11->execute(array(
          'win' => $r1['bid'],  
          'user_id' => $r2['user_id']
  ));
  $stmt13->execute();  // Clears bid table
}
```

When user press a submit button, the element value, which name is `bid` is executing by `if (isset($_POST['bid'])) {` but the `$target_time` isn't more than `$current_time` and it just simply executing `1470996804 >= 900` instead of adding 15 minutes to the form submitting date. Because it gives the result of `1470996804 >= 900`, which in the `if ($current_time >= $target_time) {` condition is true, it is executing immediately after submiting the form and `$stmt13->execute();` is executed, so it removes all table content. What should I do to make when the form is submitted, `$target_time` would be taken from the database and the `if ($current_time >= $target_time) {` condition wouldn't be true immediately but executed only after 15 minutes when the submit button was pressed?

Comment: I am struggling to understand what you are asking. Do you want the query to be executed 15 minutes after the user submits the form?

Comment: Yes, it's exactly what I want.

Comment: I don't see any errors, it just executing after the user submits the form, instead of 15 minutes delay.

Comment: I don't want to execute it every 15 minutes. It's an auction timer and if the user doesn't bid more than previous bid, then after 15 minutes the previous user wins the prize.

Comment: What's the value of `$stmt14`? It looks like that's not a valid time, so `strtotime($stmt14)` is returning `0`, and when you add 15 minutes to that it's only `900`, not a time around now.

Comment: If `$stmt14` is a PDO statement, you need to execute it and fetch the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it by myself. Yes, `$stmt14` is a PDO statement and it's fetched before the execution. Just used this condition instead: `if ($current_time >= $target_time && $stmt2 >= 1) {` where `$stmt2` is a PDO count statement, so it makes sure there is though 1 row and then it grabs the value of the last inserted row :)